# Angular routing problem: new page showing below old page

Tags: angular

I am trying to navigate to a new page in my angular app however. The new page which I created is showing below my home page which is app.component.ts

Here is my routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'billing-cycle', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'billing-cycle', component:  AppComponent},
  { path: 'customer-account-docs', component: CustomerAccountDocsComponent }
];
```

Here is my routerLink

```
 <a routerLink='/customer-account-docs'>{{msgFound.value}}</a>
```

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example of the issue? Currently there is not enough to go by

Comment: Where is your `<router-outlet>`? I guess in `AppComponent`.

Comment: <router-outlet> is in my app.component.ts. I am not getting any console errors.

Comment: When your UI stars to duplicate and when you see multiple things appearing at once, it usually means something else broke _earlier_ and Angular couldn't remove the previous UI before adding new one. Instead of swapping pages, it tries to recover from the exception by only adding a new page. Look at the console for errors in order to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have added your code might like below

**app.component.html**

```
<div>

.....<!-- Your other HTML code -->

</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- Your new page loaded here -->
```

so here when you loading the page that page loaded where your `router-outlet` tag defined

so my suggestion would be, do not add your other code in where `router-outlet` place.

Hope this will help!

Comment: let me try this, makes sense

Comment: Yes that was the error. Well from now on I know not to use app.component.ts as a login/home page. Thanks @TheParam

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem, so that others will get benefit out of it thanks

Answer (score 4):

-- If you are new to Angular make sure your `app.component.html` only contain something like this

```
<app-header></app-header> // this should contain you custom header component
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>// this should contain you custom footer component
```

-- Also make sure you got your homepage component separately and do not use the `app.component.html` as your homePage as it serves for your routing.

-- `The app.component.html` should only contain the code above.

-- Your components can then just have your static html contents.

-- You can then use the `routerLink="/securelogin"` in your HTML and make sure what you parse in the routerLink is something you configured in the `app-routing.module.ts` file e.g

```
{path: 'securelogin', component: SecureloginComponent},
  {path: 'secureregistration', component: SecureregistrationComponent},
  {path: 'forgottenpassword', component: ForgottenpasswordComponent}
```

-- Once you click on the button that contains the `routerLink`, Angular will look for that component that is mapped to the Path. In the example above `securelogin` is my path and the component mapped to that path is
`SecureloginComponent`which is mapped to the `securelogin` HTML page and it will then inject the HTML into the
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` dynamically.

-- If you got another button that got the `routerLink="/forgottenpassword"` once you click on the button/link, Angular will look for the component mapped to that path. In the example above `forgottenpassword` is my path and the component mapped to that path is `ForgottenpasswordComponent` which is mapped to the `forgottenpassword` HTML page and it will then inject the HTML into the
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` dynamically.

Note: If you follow those steps above you will have your pages displayed independently without displaying them on the same browser page.